# URL src image won't show

Tags: html, url

The same thing has been use for another image that uses HTML, and it works fine, exept for this one : https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/604447563185127426/665665552324362260/BCS_Bottom_Bar.png
And when I put the URL the same way I did for my other image and the same elements used, Yet it doesn't work.

Can someone help me fix it ?

```
<div><img width="50" height="50" src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/604447563185127426/665665552324362260/BCS_Bottom_Bar.png?width=1260&height=117"></div>
```

I've tried many alternatives to the URL, but they all don't work, I even tried changing the name.

Answer (score 0):

The img tag has two required attributes: src and alt.

So you have to change your href attribute to src.

```
<div><img width="50" height="50" src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/604447563185127426/665665552324362260/BCS_Bottom_Bar.png?width=1260&height=117"></div>
```

For more detail, take a look at; https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Answer (score 0):

It loads this way, there are no issues in your html.

As the font color is white, you maybe need to give the div a black 
background like this:

```
<div style="background: black">
<img width="50%" height="50%" src="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/604447563185127426/665665552324362260/BCS_Bottom_Bar.png">
</div>
```

I changed your width and height attributes to 50 percent.

Demo: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ohc50tx6/